# ASP.NET MVC Button doesn't trigger signed event

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried every solution that I could think of, here is the button in question:
 `<button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="Login()">Login</button>`

and here is the HTML view code :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" style="margin-top:10%">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 alert alert-info">
            <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
            <form id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="Email" id="logEmail" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" id="logPssword" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="Login()">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <a style="float:left">Forget Password ? </a><a style="float:right;cursor:pointer" onclick="SignUp()"> Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@*Design Modal With Registration form*@

<div class="modal fade" id="ShowModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h4>Registration Form</h4>
                <div id="message1">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><strong>
                            Success Message!<br />
                            send an email to your email address with confirmation link!<br />
                            please check your inbox
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="message2">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><strong>Error Message! Your Registration Is Not Complete</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="Registration">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Username" id="user" placeholder="Username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="SaveForm()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i> Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function SignUp() {
        $("#ShowModal").modal();
        $("#message1").hide();
        $("#message2").hide();
    }

    function SaveForm() {
        var name = $("#user").val();
        var pwd = $("#Password").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();

        if (name == "" || pwd == "" || email == "") {
            $("#message1").hide();
            $("#message2").show();
            return false;
        }
        var data = $("#Registration").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            url: "/Register/SaveData",
            success: function (result) {

                $("#message1").show();
                $("#message2").hide();
                $("#Registration")[0].reset();
            }
        });
    }

    var Login = function(){
        var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Register/CheckValidUser",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Fail") {
                    $("#loginForm")[0].reset();
                    $("#msg").show();
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = "/Register/AfterLogin";
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the Registration Controller :

```
using Ecommerce_Project.DBase;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ecommerce_Project.Controllers
{
    public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        Model1Container1 db = new Model1Container1();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult SaveData(Stz_Members model)
        {
            model.IsValid = true;
            db.Stz_Members.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("Registration Successfull", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }  
        public JsonResult CheckValidUser(Stz_Members model)
        {
            string result = "Fail";
            var DataItem = db.Stz_Members.Where(x => x.Email == model.Email && x.Password == model.Password).SingleOrDefault();
            if (DataItem != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = DataItem.MemberId.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = DataItem.Username.ToString();
                result = "Success";
            }
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult AfterLogin()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try chaning `var Login = function(){` to `function Login(){`

Comment: Did you try adding an event parameter to your Login function and event.preventDefault() to the first line of that function? Perhaps the form submit functionality is precluding the running of that ajax...

Comment: @RezaSaberi yes it still doesn't work

Comment: Your `Login` function at the moment doesn't prevent default or return false.   Change your `<button type='submit'` to `<button type='button'` so that it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Try `type='button'...` See [<button>: The Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) `type` property.

Comment: **NB:** You are storing passwords in plain text. Don't do that! [Secure Password Authentication Explained Simply](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54164/Secure-Password-Authentication-Explained-Simply); [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right)